R sommer package: wrong Dtable with predict.mmer for genomic prediction
I have a multi-environment trial dataset, with genotypes being tested at four environments. I want to predict environment-specific BLUPs for all genotypes. I use the mmer-function from the sommer-package in R, which runs without problem. However, when I use the predict.mmer function with the Dtable I extracted from the model output, I get an error. Below is a reproducible example which produces the same error as my dataset.
library(sommer)

ID <- factor(1:50) # 50 genotype IDs
Env <- factor(1:4) # 4 environments

ID_test <- sample(ID, 15) # sample 15 genotype IDs for making a test set

# creating a data frame with all combinations of IDs and environments
df_example <- expand.grid(ID = ID, Env = Env) %>% 
  mutate(y = rnorm(n()), # random response variable
         yNA = ifelse(ID %in% ID_test, NA, y)) # masking test IDs with NA

# run mmer model
m_examp <- mmer(yNA ~ 1, 
         random= ~ vsr(dsr(Env), ID), 
         rcov= ~ units,
         data = df_example, naMethodY = "include")

# extract Dtable, and set include to T
Dt <- m_examp$Dtable
Dt[1:3,"include"] <- T
Dt

# predict Env effects
r <- predict.mmer(object = m_examp, Dtable = Dt, D = "Env")

Predicting the environment effects produces the following error:
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "start", value = c(1, 2, 52, 102, 152 : 
  replacement has 5 rows, data has 3

I tried to solve this by extending the Dtable with two times the interaction term, to have a 5-row Dtable as the error indicates. This works, although it hardly seems the right solution.
# extend Dtable with interaction term
Dt_ext <- data.frame(type = "random", term = "Env:ID", include = T, average = F)

# predict Env:ID BLUPs
r <- predict.mmer(object = m_examp, Dtable = rbind(Dt, Dt_ext, Dt_ext), D = "ID:Env")

So the question is: what is the correct way to predict the ID:Env interaction term for this model using the sommer package? Or am I doing something else the wrong way?

What are you trying to do with this step? Dt[1:3,"include"] <- T

@zx8754 It's to modify the Dtable to include the model elements in the prediction. ?predict.mmer gives a nice explanation at the 'Dtable' argument.

You may want to try to fit the model with mmec() instead and use the predict.mmec() function. The predict function from mmer is very messy and I haven't been able to debug. I am working to move the mmer function to use the same formulae and functions than mmec, hopefully that will be done by Q3.

Using mmec on the same dataset yields the following error:
Error in vsc(dsc(Env), isc(ID), Gu = GRM_sparse) :
Gu matrix is not of class dgCMatrix. Please correct.
However, class(GRM_sparse) yields  "dsCMatrix". It is converted to a dsCMatrix with as(GRM, "CsparseMatrix").

Could fitted.mmer on the mmer model described above be a workaround? This yields reasonable results.
fitted.mmer(m_examp)$dataWithFitted

Can you try:  GRM <- as(GRM_sparse, Class="dgCMatrix"), then use that matrix in the model.

Now this error is solved indeed; it now yields this: "Error in .subscript.2ary(x, i, j, drop = drop) : subscript out of bounds" although the same dataframes/matrices are used as in the mmer model. My dataframe is in long format (dim = 1216x7) and my GRM_sparse matrix has a dim of 304x304 (genotype ID's)

Can you share a minimal example? Is difficult to know what's going on without a minimal example (https://github.com/covaruber/sommer/issues).

I found what's causing the error, and posted a minimal example on the github page. Thanks for the efforts!
